# How to assert a func to a type by reflect?

Tags: function, go, methods, reflection, types

I am writing an RPC service in Go. I don't know how to convert a struct method to a `Handler` func.

What I tried:

```
type TestService struct{}

func (TestService) Foo(a int) error {
    return nil
}

type Handle func(a int) error

func TestHandle(t *testing.T) {
    ts := new(TestService)
    val := reflect.ValueOf(ts)
    // typ := reflect.TypeOf(ts)

    // fmt.Println(val.Method(0).Interface())
    // fmt.Println(val.Method(0).Type().ConvertibleTo(reflect.TypeOf(new(Handle))))

    switch reflect.Indirect(val).Method(0).Interface().(type) {
    case Handle:
        fmt.Println(" okokok " )
    default:
        fmt.Println(reflect.Indirect(val).Method(0).Type())
    }
}
```

But it fails. How should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `TestService.Foo` is of type `func(a int) error`, which is not the same as type `Handle` (`Handle` has the same underlying type, but it is a new, distinct type).

You have to check for this exact type:

```
case func(a int) error:
    fmt.Println(" okokok ")
```

With this change, output will be:

```
=== RUN   TestHandle
 okokok 
--- PASS: TestHandle (0.00s)
PASS
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/E3TvJ5Dtl48).

Note that you can do the same with a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), e.g.:

```
if _, ok := reflect.Indirect(val).Method(0).Interface().(func(a int) error); ok {
    fmt.Println(" okokok ")
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lxJHAbj_L40).

Also note that if you do want to use the `Handle` type definition, you could check if the function value is [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to a variable of `Handle` type. Using reflection, this check essentially means if the type of the method is assignable to the type of `Handle`.

This is how it would look like:

```
th := reflect.TypeOf(Handle(nil))
if reflect.Indirect(val).Method(0).Type().AssignableTo(th) {
    fmt.Println(" okokok ")
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/si9hlokjxJe).

### Obtaining the function value

Solutions above only check if the given method is of the given function type. If you also need the function value (so you can call it), this is how you can do it:

When using type switch ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CE4Ah9hZkcS)):

```
switch hf := reflect.Indirect(val).Method(0).Interface().(type) {
case func(a int) error:
    fmt.Println(" okokok ", hf(0))
default:
    fmt.Println(reflect.Indirect(val).Method(0).Type())
}
```

When using type assertion ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/glrsIa4I4IA)):

```
if hf, ok := reflect.Indirect(val).Method(0).Interface().(func(a int) error); ok {
    fmt.Println(" okokok ", hf(0))
}
```

Using [`Value.Convert()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Convert) ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7PPrmYcKzKN)):

```
m := reflect.Indirect(val).Method(0)
th := reflect.TypeOf(Handle(nil))
if m.Type().AssignableTo(th) {
    var hf Handle = m.Convert(th).Interface().(Handle)
    fmt.Println(" okokok ", hf(0))
}
```

Comment: I changed the receive, but panic .
[https://play.golang.org/p/gvA55CClCQ7](https://play.golang.org/p/gvA55CClCQ7)

Comment: @mrjJs Because you used a pointer receiver, so the method is not in the method set of the non-pointer type. It works if you remove the `reflect.Indirect()` call: https://play.golang.org/p/8mDHN0gRs16